# Select existing video from Photos in FireMonkey app (iOS / Android)

Tags: android, ios, delphi, video, firemonkey

I have searched around and cannot find any examples of how to select a video already
recorded in the Photo Gallery, then saving it in my iOS/Android app.

There is one for selecting photos, but it returns a `TBitmap` in the `OnDidFinish` event.

Note: I'm not referring to recording a video through my FireMonkey app, which there is already an example.

Can anyone give me some pointers to get started on selecting an existing video in iOS/Android?

Delphi 10.4.1 with FireMonkey (64-bit Android/64-bit iOS).

Comment: I spent a lot of time to have a FileSelector, and the best I find is the one from Kastri https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/FilesSelector

Comment: I went through this example in the past but it returns the filename... so I'm not sure how I can get the video from it.

Comment: @Bosshoss FilesSelector does not allow selection of files from the photos albums. I am however working on releasing Delphi code (finally) that does allow access to those. Anyone who is interested can join my Slack workspace at https://slack.delphiworlds.com and ask to join the "beta" for this code